# How can I use Stripe Pricing Table to first require Google Auth before continuing to the Stripe Checkout flow?

Tags: stripe-payments, user-experience

I'm currently trying to determine if there's a way to navigate a user from [Stripe's dynamic pricing table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table) to a custom sign-up page *before* continuing to Stripe Checkout.

The React web app I'm building is dependant on being linked to a Google account (it uses Google APIs) so I would not want to fall back to username & password login.

Ideal onboarding flow would be:

1. User sees Stripe pricing plan table, and chooses their ideal option
2. User gets prompted to "sign in with Google", and gets redirected to Stripe Checkout
3. After checkout, user gets redirected to app's account page

Currently I can only think of the following two flows:

- **Flow A (Stripe-first):**

  1. User sees Stripe pricing plan table, and chooses their ideal option
  2. User completes Stripe checkout and gets redirected to app prompting them to "link your Google Account". They also get a similar email with a button to link their accounts.
  3. If user does not link their account, they are in limbo with an active Stripe subscription. Reminder emails are needed, etc.
- **Flow B (Google Auth first):**

  1. User can't see plans or price before signing up (at least not dynamic, from Stripe)
  2. User signs in with Google and then lands on a page in the app showing the pricing plans
  3. User chooses their plan, completes the Checkout and is done.

Any ideas on how to achieve the ideal flow, or perhaps alternative ways (UX) to approach user onboarding?

Comment: If the customer doesn't link their account first in Flow A, the email address filled in the checkout page might be different from their Google sign-in. I think Flow B will be better since you're able to pass [`customer-email`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#customer-email) and ensure emails in both checkout and sign-in are the same.

Comment: For security reasons, I do not recommend you use pricing tables at this time. Even if you hide it behind a Google login, once the hacker logs in, they can take the code (`<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script><stripe-pricing-table .../>`), add it to a local HTML file, and proceed to card test your checkout all day. Better to use the API to create a checkout session in a cloud function and return the sessioned checkout link per user after they authenticate.